# How to use output from function?

Tags: javascript, function, return

I have a function in file dirExistEmpty.js and I need to use output from the function in main.js. Bellow is my code but it is not working.

dirExistEmpty.js

```js
  function dirExistEmpty(imgF) {
    const emptyDir = require('empty-dir');
    const fs = require('fs');
    if (fs.existsSync(`${imgF}`)) {
      console.log(`Directory exists! ${imgF}`);
      emptyDir(`${imgF}`, function(err, stdout) {
        if (err) {
          console.error('errorrr',err);
       } else {
          console.log('Directory is empty:', stdout);
          let empty = `${stdout}`
          return empty;
          console.log(`Directory is empty: ${empty}`);
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      let empty = true;
      return empty;
    }
  }
    module.exports = {dirExistEmpty}
```

main.js

```js
    const dirExistEmpty = require('./dirExistEmpty.js');
    let isEmpty = dirExistEmpty.dirExistEmpty('c:\\AAA');
    let empty = isEmpty.empty;
    console.log("Is empty ?", empty);
```

Comment: main.js
----
const path = require("path")
const os = require("os")
const dirExistEmpty = require('./dirExistEmpty.js');
const homeDir=os.homedir();

let path1= path.join(homeDir,"..","..", "AAA");
let isEmpty=dirExistEmpty.dirExistEmpty(path1);
let empty = isEmpty;
console.log("Is empty ?", empty);
------dirExistEmpty.js

function dirExistEmpty(imgF){
    const emptyDir = require('empty-dir');
    const fs = require('fs');
    if (fs.existsSync(imgF)){
        return emptyDir.sync(imgF);   
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }
  }
module.exports = {dirExistEmpty}

Comment: dnt know why , but I am not able to post the code in proper format :(
Hope it resolve your problem